# Can I open a new window and change the DOM of the calling window in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom, window.open

First I would like to say that I've been programming JavaScript for about 3 months now and also that I'm not very concerned with solving this problem by the standards or best practices. My main concern is learning to use the DOM. I don't want to use any jQuery because I'm not familiar with it.

I'm trying to make a non-profesional "login" function on my page, using JavaScript and the DOM. To begin with I was using "login" screen that would be displayed "hidden" initially and then be displayed "block" when in use. This worked fine and looked really good when I added a darkened screen behind the "login" screen by adding less opacity (0.1 opacity) to the main part of the page that's beneath the "login screen".

This (the opacity) would return to normal when I closed the "login" screen. So you can see all the stuff is happening within the same page using the same DOM. OK, this is how I wanted it to work: you create a username then you your create a password. Boom, finished!

But here's the problem: after you create a username and password I want it to say "Hello (username here)" where the login link initially was. I could just use the DOM and insert the username into the HTML page, but when I submit the form that is the login function the page gets reloaded and the changes to the DOM become erased!

So now I can tell you about the solution  I thought of: make the form (login page) be in a new window, so when the form is submitted (and the DOM is manipulated) the new window is reloaded and then subsequently closes leaving the changes to the main pages DOM intact. Only problem is I can't figure out how to do this. You could probably say that's a major problem hahaha.

So, can I manipulate the parent windows (i.e. the calling window) DOM from the new window?

Comment: Are you using a server side technology (ASP, PHP, JSP...)? or it is just plain html+js? What ever is receiving your submitted form is capable to generate its html including the new `Hello [username here]` message.

Comment: I'm using plain html+js. I don't send the form anywhere. Like this: <form name="create" action=#"> I just looked up ASP so I'm not very familiar with it. I don't do anything server side but should I use ASP anyway to generate the new html?

Comment: If you don't need to post the form, then don't do it :) jeje, just "detect" user's click on the submit button in order to "delete" the login div (your first approach) but don't allow it to do the post, so you can manipulate the DOM as you like.

Comment: Thank you for the idea of not posting the form. On submitting the form I just validate input then when it's validated as an ok, I can manipulate the DOM and then I just use preventDefault or window.event.returnValue (for IE) to prevent the form from being posted and the page doesn't reload. Problem solved. I just needed a good idea thank you Romier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In response to your answer: you can modify the caller window's DOM by using `window.opener.document` from the new window;

`window.opener` is a reference to the caller window (if any, otherwise `null`), but only if both windows are from the [same domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)).

**NOTE:** Is it a small webpage or you are going to do a lot of DOM manipulation on a web site/application via javascript? In the later case you should use a javascript library/framework (I recommend jQuery) in order to do the dirty job more easily.

Comment: Answer to your note. It's just a small webpage that I'm making for the purpose of practicing webpage devolpment. I have heard alot about JQuery and I will look into it when I need it/feel ready for it. Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

A popup window can find the window that opened it using the `opener` variable.

If both the popup window and the original window originate from the same domain, then the popup window can indeed modify the HTML of the original window.

If the popup window and the original window contain content from a different domain, then they can't see the HTML of each other - due to the cross-origin protection that browsers put in place.

Comment: The opener worked very well in my situation. But is the opener a variable? I thought it was a method?