# How do I open a website from a pop-out window?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to open a website from a window that opens when I click a button. Here is screen capture of what that looks like:

http://www.flickr.com/photos/92807764@N06/8617593002/in/photostream

Here's how I do the pop-out window:

```
<a onClick="MyWindow=window.open('availability.php','MyWindow','toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no, menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,width=600,height=300'); return false;">
    <button class="Über-clean" type="submit"style="float:right;" >Check Availability</button>
</a>
```

So I click on "Check Avalilability" and then the window comes out with the "book now" button. What I want to do is when I click "Book now", it opens up a page on the original home page, in other words where "Check availability" is this is what happens when I click "book now":

http://www.flickr.com/photos/92807764@N06/8616499063/in/photostream

The page opens up in the window itself, which I don't want. How do I open up booker.php in the original tab?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to do your pop-up with ajax and some in-window pop up like fancybox (jquery)? That way you won't have to struggle with sending data back to the parent window...

Comment: I am guessing you are not sending the correct querystring parameters to availability.php so it redirects to the main page. We can not solve this for you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13782585/using-javascript-can-i-open-a-new-window-and-then-change-the-dom-of-the-calling

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="test.html" target="windowName">TEST</a>
```

If a window or frame named "windowName" already exists, the page is loaded into it. Otherwise, a new window is created first.

The window name must be a single word (only letters, digits and underscore and cannot begin with a digit).

There are four predefined targets:

```
_blank  always opens a new window.
_self   always opens in the current window or frame.
_parent opens in the parent frame, if any, otherwise as _self.
_top    opens in entire browser window, even if there are frames.
```

For example in javascript
window.open("test.html","windowName");